# what's the meaning/origin of 呲东西停不下来桑?

Tags: meaning, characters, culture, slang

I came across this sentence that is puzzling me, especially the last characters:
**呲东西停不下来桑**
Its meaning should be "I can't stop eating" but I cannot really understand where is coming from.
There is no other context, it's a stand-alone sentence basically.
I have been told that the last few characters part is very specific to youth native culture so I thought was some kind of young/net slang or a reference to pop culture, but any web search did not return any light.
Do you know what's the meaning/origin behind it?

Comment: The sentence emulates a dialectal pronunciation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its origin is 吃东西停不下来。
吃 and 呲 is similar in their pronunciation.
桑 might come from Japanese appellation systems（さん）.(I did not verify it)

This is a native expression. The purpose of this transform is to express a lovely feeling. Similar to adding some emoji （你好 (｡◕ฺˇε ˇ◕ฺ｡））or using double characters(吃饭饭 睡觉觉). There is no importance and can not be used in solemn occasions.

It is enough for you to understand it. No need to be confused in it.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense